# Failed Vertex re-running

Tags: hive, tez

I am trying to run hive query on EMR in was using tez. I am facing below error. I am running this query on 20 node cluster. I am running below query.

```
insert overwrite table temp_table partition(hour)
select a,b,c,hour
from stats_temp_table;



Status: Failed
Vertex re-running, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1523328121104_1005_1_00
Vertex re-running, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1523328121104_1005_1_00
Vertex re-running, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1523328121104_1005_1_00
Vertex re-running, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1523328121104_1005_1_00
Vertex re-running, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1523328121104_1005_1_00
Vertex re-running, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1523328121104_1005_1_00
Vertex failed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1523328121104_1005_1_01, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1523328121104_1005_1_01_000002, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in Fetcher {Map_1} #2
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:301)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:285)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map_1: Shuffle failed with too many fetch failures and insufficient progress!failureCounts=5, pendingInputs=12, fetcherHealthy=false, reducerProgres`enter code here`sedEnough=false, reducerStalled=true
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.isShuffleHealthy(ShuffleScheduler.java:977)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.copyFailed(ShuffleScheduler.java:718)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.setupConnection(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:376)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.copyFromHost(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:260)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.fetchNext(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:178)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:191)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:54)
    ... 5 more
, errorMessage=Shuffle Runner Failed:org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in Fetcher {Map_1} #2
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:301)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:285)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map_1: Shuffle failed with too many fetch failures and insufficient progress!failureCounts=5, pendingInputs=12, fetcherHealthy=false, reducerProgressedEnough=false, reducerStalled=true
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.isShuffleHealthy(ShuffleScheduler.java:977)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.copyFailed(ShuffleScheduler.java:718)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.setupConnection(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:376)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.copyFromHost(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:260)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.fetchNext(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:178)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:191)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:54)
    ... 5 more
```